# How to apply the law of quadratic reciprocity?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

[image]

Looking at this example, how does 103 get simplified to 10? It seems like they are simplifying it using a modulo but what is the modulo and how is it determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left (\frac{a}{p}\right )\equiv_{p}a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ is over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so $103\equiv_{31}10$.